# Grothendieck group and an almost localization

Tags: ct.category-theory, algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $T$ be a small triangulated category and let $S\subset T$ be a full triangulated subcategory. We denote this embedding by $I: S\rightarrow T$.
Let $F: T\rightarrow S$ be a triangulated functor such that $F\circ I= \mathrm{id}$. Define $L= I\circ F$.
Suppose that

1. $L\circ L=L$.
2. If $F(a)=0$ then $a=0$ ($a\in T$).
3. We do not assume the existence of a natural transformation $id_{T}\rightarrow L$.

Clearly the induced map between Grothendieck groups $K_{0}(T)\rightarrow K_{0}(S)$ is surjective.
My question is if this induced map is also injective ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general, no. Let $S$ be any triangulated category, and consiser the inclusion of the left (say) summand $S \to S \times S$.

You can choose the functor $F$ to be the direct sum functor $\oplus : S \times S \to S$, which is clearly conservative, and is a retraction of that inclusion. Condition 1. follows from the fact that $FI = id_S$ and is not really an extra assumption. In that case it's clear that $K_0(F)$ is an isomorphism (equivalently, $K_0(I)$ is an isomorphism) if and only if $K_0(S) = 0$.